# File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. Searched Location:

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-play-services

I'm trying to add my app to Firebase, but it keeps saying

`> File google-services.json is missing.`

Full error in the below pic:

[image]

even though I've added it to the right place(I have added it to root folder)

[image]

I read some articles but my problem still persists. Any help? My app version is (ionic-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are using firebase plugin in ionic, correct me if I'm wrong. I had this issue once i was implementing firebase push notification in ionic app. Simply what i did was Copied `google-services.json` to below paths

- `src/app`
- `platforms/android`
- `platforms/android/app`
- `platforms/ios`

Then i build my ionic app and it successfully build unsigned apk.

Answer (score 0):

**Only Copy** `google-services.json` to the below paths

```
platforms/android/app
```

No need to copy it to any other folders